# Cannot access class "android.arch.core.util.Function"

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

Hello I cannot create code impl., error like in title

```
Transformations.switchMap(mLiveData, listOfDamages -> { doSth()})
```

or

```
Transformations.map(liveData){
            doSth()    
            }
```

I cannot applied lambda function as second parameter. Full error states

> Cannot access class "android.arch.core.util.Function". Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

I haven't any visible confilicts - mean that project is compiling

**EDIT**

downgrading support library from 26.1.0 to 26.0.2 and it started working

I've opened issue here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66894924

Comment: Could you show us your build.grade ?

Comment: Yes, it is available on issuetracker